# tarifa +10kW España automatizar por columnas

Tags: excel, lógica

Tengo una duda en este código:
Necesito colocar por franjas a que periodo corresponde el precio asignado.
Son 6 franjas de precios

```
P1= F6 , P2= F7, P3 = f8 ,P4 = f9, P5 = f10, P6 = f11
```

diría según resultados que hay algunos periodos que no me entran en el bucle.
son 4 periodos con varios meses :

```
Enero,febrero,Julio, Diciembre seria Temporada Alta
0-8 P6 , 8-9 P2 , 9-14 P1 , 14-18 P2 , 18-22 P1 , 22-0 P2


marzo,noviembre seria Temporada Media Alta
0-8 P6 , 8-9 P3, 9-14 P2 , 14-18 P3 , 18-22 P2 , 22-0 P3


junio,agosto,septiembre seria Temporada Media 
0-8 P6 , 8-9 P4 , 9-14 P3 , 14-18 P4, 18-22 P3 , 22-0 P4


abril,mayo,octubre seria Temporada Baja
0-8 P6 , 8-9 P5 , 9-14 P4 , 14-18 P5 , 18-22 P4, 22-0 P5
```

Designo primero fechas festivas y sábados , domingos para asignar precio mas barato P6

El código me está dado fallos con las franjas horarias , si tenéis alguna idea o que me falla algún paréntesis o plantear el SI , comentadme

```
=SI(O(A2=FECHANUMERO("1/1/19");A2=FECHANUMERO("6/1/19");A2=FECHANUMERO("19/3/19");A2=FECHANUMERO("14/04/19");A2=FECHANUMERO("15/04/19");A2=FECHANUMERO("18/4/19");A2=FECHANUMERO("28/04/19");A2=FECHANUMERO("23/06/19");A2=FECHANUMERO("24/06/19");A2=FECHANUMERO("15/08/19");A2=FECHANUMERO("9/10/19");A2=FECHANUMERO("12/10/19");A2=FECHANUMERO("1/11/19");A2=FECHANUMERO("6/12/19");A2=FECHANUMERO("8/12/19");A2=FECHANUMERO("1/1/20");A2=FECHANUMERO("6/1/20");A2=FECHANUMERO("19/3/20");DIASEM(A2;2)>5);'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$11;SI(O(MES(A2)=1;MES(A2)=2;MES(A2)=7;MES(A2)=12);SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("00:00:00");B2<=VALOR("8:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$11;SI(Y(B2>VALOR("08:00:00");B2<=VALOR("9:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$7;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("09:00:00");B2<=VALOR("14:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$6;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("14:00:00");B2<=VALOR("18:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$7;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("18:00:00");B2<=VALOR("22:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$6;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("22:00:00");B2<=VALOR("00:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$7;SI(O(MES(A2)=3;MES(A2)=11);SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("00:00:00");B2<=VALOR("8:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$11;SI(Y(B2>VALOR("08:00:00");B2<=VALOR("9:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$8;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("09:00:00");B2<=VALOR("14:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$7;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("14:00:00");B2<=VALOR("18:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$8;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("18:00:00");B2<=VALOR("22:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$7;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("22:00:00");B2<=VALOR("00:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$8;SI(O(MES(A2)=6;MES(A2)=8;MES(A2)=11);SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("00:00:00");B2<=VALOR("8:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$11;SI(Y(B2>VALOR("08:00:00");B2<=VALOR("9:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$9;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("09:00:00");B2<=VALOR("14:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$8;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("14:00:00");B2<=VALOR("18:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$9;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("18:00:00");B2<=VALOR("22:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$8;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("22:00:00");B2<=VALOR("00:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$9;SI(O(MES(A2)=4;MES(A2)=5;MES(A2)=11);SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("00:00:00");B2<=VALOR("8:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$11;SI(Y(B2>VALOR("08:00:00");B2<=VALOR("9:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$10;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("09:00:00");B2<=VALOR("14:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$9;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("14:00:00");B2<=VALOR("18:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$10;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("18:00:00");B2<=VALOR("22:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$9;SI(Y(B2>=VALOR("22:00:00");B2<=VALOR("00:00:00"));'ESTABLECIMIENTO DE PRECIOS '!$F$10;0)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con un cuarto de ese codigo deberias haber parado... Esto parace un trabajo para bucarV (o buscarH, o algo por ese camino)... si decis que te da fallos, tenes que mostrar que error.. si es un error de que da un valor incorrecto.. es algo que deberias validar vos, no vamos a poder hacerlo por vos...

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Creo que sería mejor que pusieras un ejemplo de datos y el resultado esperado. Tu formula es larguísima y leerla es complicado.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.